# No onTap response in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
class _MainTestState extends State<MainTest> {
  void setstateham() {
    setState(() {

    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double tophe = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    final pro = Provider.of<Pro>(context);
    US(context);

    GlobalKey<CircularMenuState> key = GlobalKey<CircularMenuState>();
    
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: pro.mainColor,

        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: tophe),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
```

This is the top part of the widget containing the `setState` refresh function.

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(305.w,23.h,0,0),
            width: 80.w,
            height: 80.h,
            child: CircularMenu(
              toggleButtonSize: 25.0,
              toggleButtonColor: pro.backColor_jinblue,
              toggleButtonIconColor: Colors.white,
              startingAngleInRadian: 0.45 * 3.14,
              endingAngleInRadian: 0.95 *  3.14,

              key: key,
              items: [
                CircularMenuItem(

                  icon: Icons.settings,
                  onTap: () {
                    pro.changeMainColor();
                    print('click1');
                    setstateham();
                  },
                  color: pro.backColor_jinblue,
                  iconColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                CircularMenuItem(
                  icon: Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                  onTap: () {
                    pro.changeMainColor();
                    print('click2');
                    setstateham();
                  },
                  color: pro.backColor_jinblue,
                  iconColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                CircularMenuItem(
                  icon: Icons.invert_colors,
                  onTap: () {
                    pro.changeMainColor();
                    print('click3');
                    setstateham();
                  },
                  color: pro.backColor_jinblue,
                  iconColor: Colors.white,
                ),

              ],
            ) ,
          ),
```

`onTap` is unresponsive code

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device SM N971N...
Reloaded 1 of 775 libraries in 1,197ms.
I/ViewRootImpl@7cd6bbe[MainActivity]( 3299): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@7cd6bbe[MainActivity]( 3299): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@7cd6bbe[MainActivity]( 3299): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@7cd6bbe[MainActivity]( 3299): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@7cd6bbe[MainActivity]( 3299): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@7cd6bbe[MainActivity]( 3299): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/ViewRootImpl@7cd6bbe[MainActivity]( 3299): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@7cd6bbe[MainActivity]( 3299): ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

When the button is pressed, the `setState` or print itself in the `onTap` does not proceed, it just pops up the ViewPostIme that the touch is somewhere on the screen. When I touch the circlemenuitem in the emulator on the pc, the ViewPostIme pointer doesn't even come up and there is just nothing.

If you make another button and put it `onPressed` it works. If I create another widget and try `onTap`, there is no response as well.